Install DKMS on Rhel8.8
Newbie here.
I want to install dkms for my RHEL 8.8. I learnt that its not supported on RHEL and has to be fetched via epel.
I ran the below step
yum install /home/abhi/Downloads/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm 

and got success for it.
But ran into below errors
[root@localhost src]# sudo yum install dkms
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                                                                                                     
0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:02    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'epel':
- Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates 
for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel- 
8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir [SSL certificate problem: unable to get 
local issuer certificate]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': 
Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: 
Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for 
https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel
8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir 
[SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]

Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel': 
Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: 
Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates 
for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel- 
8&arch=x86_64&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir 
[SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]

Any idea what's going wrong or how to fix ?

Was your /home/abhi/Downloads/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm file an old one? If you're not sure, get a fresh one from https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

Clear yum cache and try again

does not work after yum cahce. and yes its latest version
